# How to start a new project and host it at launchpad.net?

Tags: programming, development, launchpad

I'm planning to start a new project. However, I can't find a really simple documentation to getting started with launchpad.net.

**What should I do to create a new project?**

I will appreciate any kind of suggestion of good documentation. So feel free to give all your help answering the following. Thanks!

Comment: Several good questions here but they should be separated into different questions.

Comment: Done. Now will be 3 singular questions. Thanks for you suggestion!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## How to create a project

I will show how to create a project on Launchpad. I recommend that you go to [staging.launchpad.net](https://staging.launchpad.net) to create a test project first. This is what I will do in my example. The process is exactly the same on [launchpad.net](http://launchpad.net).

First, click 'Register a project' on the home page.

[image]

Enter the project information.

[image]

Add extra details including a lengthy description, a homepage URL and a licence (choose GNU GPL v3 if you are not sure which to pick).

[image]

Click 'Complete Registration' to create your project.

See https://help.launchpad.net/Code/QuickStart for how to host your project code.

There are tools available to make code hosting easier. [Quickly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly)  is a useful tool for helping you to get started with programming on Ubuntu using python, bzr and Launchpad.

Also to simplify the code hosting and bzr version control, you can use the excellent [Ground Control](http://ground-control.org/) which integrates your Launchpad projects into the Nautilus file manager.

I also find [nautilus-bzr](http://packages.ubuntu.com/p/nautilus-bzr)
a useful tool because it provides emblems showing the status of files in a bzr branch.

Comment: Please consider linking to https://help.launchpad.net/Code/QuickStart

Comment: One should also mention quickly from Canonical: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly ( you just need to type 'quickly release' to release your project into Launchpad )

Comment: groundcontrol and nautilus-bzr seem to be available for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) only.

Comment: And https://staging.launchpad.net/ is offline, but maybe it is temporary.

Comment: quickly is available for Precise and Trusty.